# Swift: I want to navigate to several viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I want to go to the several view controller when I click the table rows.
So I made the code like below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{

        var targetId = ""
        var targetController: UITableViewController!

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 2:
            targetId = "TableView1"
            targetController = TableViewController1()
        case 2:
            targetId = "TableView2"
            targetController = TableViewController2()
        case 2:
            targetId = "TableView3"
            targetController = TableViewController3()
        default:
            return
        }

        let detailView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: targetId) as! targetController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)

}
```

But I can see the error message "use of undeclared type 'targetController'".
How can I navigate to several view controllers?

Comment: Because targetController is Object not class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast an object to a variable (instance).

However if all controllers are subclasses of `UIViewController` you need no type cast at all

```
let detailView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: targetId)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailView, animated: true)
```